# Utility function to gererate new columns by each part of a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am pretty new to python and programming. Thus i am still writing some general utility functions, which i later plan to always use again. This one would be to extract each part of a datetime column (year, month, day, hour, etc.) and put it in new columns. To make sure that different datetime columns in the dataframe do not get mixed up, i would like to take the original column name into the new columns. What i got ist the following function:

```
def datetime_to_cols(df, col_to_convert):

    col_name_lst = list(df.columns)
    i = col_name_lst.index(col_to_convert)

    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'year'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.year
    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'month'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.month
    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'day'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.day

    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'hour'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.hour
    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'minute'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.minute
    df[df[col_name_lst[i]]+'second'] = df[col_to_convert].dt.second
```

But i get the following error:

```
datetime_to_cols(train, dateCreated)
datetime_to_cols(train, dateCreated)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-c5bd61d3b95b> in <module>
----> 1 datetime_to_cols(train, dateCreated)

NameError: name 'dateCreated' is not defined
```

dateCreated is the column name which contains the timestamp in datetime format in the df train. Could anyone help me out?

Many thanks already in advance!

Comment: If dateCreated is the column name, you need to pass it as a string ```'dateCreated'```

Comment: Late, since i did not really check stackoverflow since then (at least not logged in) but thanks a lot for pointing in the right direction @Eric Truett! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass column name as a string not as a variable.

```
datetime_to_cols(train, "dateCreated")
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument should be passed as follows:

```
datetime_to_cols(train, "dateCreated")
```